# PC doesn't boot and shows "No init found"

Tags: 10.10, boot, recovery-mode

When I turn on my PC, it says:

#### Case 1

```
BusyBox v1.17.1 (ubuntu 1:1.17.1-10 ubuntu1) buil-in shell (ash)
enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)_
```

#### Case 2

In Recovery Mode, it says:

```
706-4e 6e-9416-17889748 bbd onb /root failed:input/output error
Begin:running/scripts/local booting...done
done.
Begin:running/scripts/local booting...mount:mounting/dev on /root/dev failed :no such file or directory
done.
mount:mounting/sys on /root/sys failed :no such file or directory
mount:mounting/proc on /root/proc failed :no such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have a requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init=bootarg.

BusyBox v1.17.1 (ubuntu 1:1.17.1-10 ubuntu1) buil-in shell (ash)
enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)_
[ 34.664739] atkbd serio0: unknown key pressed (translated set2, code 0xd9 on isa0060/serio0)....
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Boot from the Ubuntu Live CD;
> 2. Open/Run Terminal;
> 3. Type: `sudo fdisk -l` (to get the device name) then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
>
>    ```
>    Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
>    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
>    Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
>    Disk identifier: **********
>
>    Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
>    /dev/sda1 * 1 30238 242886703+ 83 Linux
>    /dev/sda2 30239 30401 1309297+ 5 Extended
>    /dev/sda5 30239 30401 1309266 82 Linux swap / Solaris
>    ```
>
>    The device name for my friend's system based on the above: `/dev/sda1`
> 4. Type: `sudo fsck /dev/sda1` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
> 5. Restart the system and boot normally.

[**Source**](http://pinoy-computing-tips.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-ubuntu-error-no-init-found.html#ixzz21i8Uhho6)

Answer (score 0):

The above really doesn't cover all the bases of this error.

You might need to boot from Live CD, then chroot into the system. (bind mount /dev, mount /proc), and then run `update-grub`, and then `grub-install /dev/root-device`

I've done this many times, and it really needs to be made easier, and also made possible when you can't run the target's binaries, which I only managed to do by hacking the grub-mkconfig script, which is a uber-PITA.